# Can I file California State tax as a part year resident/non resident, if I am filing Federal tax as a Resident?

Tags: united-states, california, state-income-tax, h-1b-visa

I am on H1B since October 1, 2017. I am filing Form 1040 for my Federal taxes, which I will file after May 2018, filing for an extension. How should I file my State tax? I live in California. Does California have any provision for treating "part-year residents" as "residents", if filed for an extension?

Comment: Did you have any income in 2017 in another country or a US state other than California? Will you pay any 2017 taxes in any other jurisdiction besides USA and California?

Comment: All of my income in 2017 is from California alone.

Answer (score 2):

If you moved into or out of California in the middle of the year, then you are a part-year resident of California -- resident only for the part of the year you resided in California. This has nothing to do with whether you are a "resident alien" or "nonresident alien" for federal tax purposes.

Comment: Out of California, only for a brief visit to another visit. I did not really "move out" of California. In that case, will I be a resident for tax purposes? Also, has this got nothing to do with the type of Visa? I was on H1B only from Oct 1, 2017 to Dec 31, 2017 in 2017

Comment: @Josh: It does not have to do with your immigration status. I would say you were probably a California resident for the whole year, although the definition of "resident" for California taxes is kind of murky. In any case, the only difference between resident and nonresident is that residents are taxed on out of state income. Since you did not have any income from outside California, there would be no difference between resident and nonresident anyway.